# Can't get data from JSON object from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I want to get 'userRole' of logged in user from my JSON object requested from my firebase database. So I tried the following code:

```
ionViewWillLoad(){
    this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
        this.ref = user.uid;
        this.userService.getUserById(this.ref).subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data
            console.log(this.data);
        })
    });
}
```

File I get from my database looks something like this:

```
0:{$value: "admin@gmail.com", $key: "email", $exists: ƒ}
1:{$value: "password", $key: "password", $exists: ƒ}
2:{$value: 1, $key: "userRole", $exists: ƒ}
3:{$value: "", $key: "worksFor", $exists: ƒ}
```

How can I access "userRole" from this JSON object? I tried 'data.userRole', 'data[2].$value', but these don't work.

Following is the code to add a new user to database:

```
getUserById(id){
    return this.afd.list('/users/' + id);
}

register(user){
    return this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).then(data => {
        this.afd.object('/users/' + data.uid).update(user);
    });
}
```

Is there something wrong with the way I add data to the database?

Thank You!

Comment: I think you have 2 info in you database - authentication table and /users/ realtime database "table", so which one do you want to access?

Comment: I want to get data from /user/ table, based on currently logged in user @Makah

Comment: if you are receiving the data, can you try accessing it via data["userRole"]

Comment: @ayudh thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has several products, I think you will need to use two of them. [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) to control user authentication and [Realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) to save other informations as Address, phone, and other data related to your project.

In my case, I prefer to wrap users information in a service - [my example](https://github.com/makah/rateSiteFirebase/blob/bd23c7f9b29660896ac3442b5b25fb4597bd0394/src/app/services/authentication.service.ts). Fragment:

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

constructor(public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

load() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((auth) => {
            this.authState = auth
            resolve(true);
        },
            err => reject(err)
        );
    });

    return promise;
}

get userID(): string {
    return this.authenticated ? this.authState.uid : '';
}

retrieveUser(): any {
    if(this.authenticated === undefined){
        console.log('You need to authenticate first.');
        return null;
    }

    this.user = this.db.object('/users/'+ this.userID)
                    .valueChanges()
                    .publishReplay(1)
                    .refCount();


    return this.user;
}
```

An I use like this:

```
this.authService.retrieveUser().subscribe(user => {
  this.user = user;  
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like magic. The error was that I was adding an object and requesting a list from the database.